# convert this javascript to Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, tailwind-css, darkmode

Hi i am trying to add darkmode to my project and im following a tutorial but it seems that its a javascript tutorial instaed of a vue one and this section of code is not working and was wondering if someone could help me in converting it to vue 3. this is the tutorial link if it helps. many thanks https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-add-dark-mode-to-your-next-js-project-using-tailwind-css-3d460a768d1c

```
    <button onClick={() > setDarkMode(!darkMode)}>
      {darkMode ? (
        <SunIcon size="4rem" />
      ) : (
        <MoonIcon size="4rem" />
      )}
    </button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i can't see the page you provided, but I will directly convert the code.

```
<button @click="darkmode=!darkmode"> 
 <MoonIcon v-if="darkmode" size="4rem" />
 <SunIcon v-else size="4rem" />
</button>
```

if you are using **composition api**:

```
setup(){
   const darkmode = ref(false)

   return {darkmode}
}
```

if it's **options api**:

```
data(){
   return {
      darkmode: false
   }
}
```

Comment: thankyou appriciate it. annoyingly though i couldn't get the whole dark mode thing to work, just not sure how to get the whole thing to work. i thought there would have been somekind of tutorial for this type of thing. in vue with tailwind. thanks for your help though.